# Function variable overloading

Tags: typescript, overloading, currying

I have a curried function where I need to overload the returned function signature (simplified example):

```
const foo = (bar: string) => (tag: string, children?: string[]) => {
const foo = (bar: string) => (tag: string, props: Object, children?: string[]) => {
  // Do something
};
```

Overloading works great with class methods or function declarations with the `function` keyword, but I haven't been able to get it to work with curried functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
type MyCurriedFunction = {
    (tag: string, children?: string[]): void;
    (tag: string, props: Object, children?: string[]): void;
}

const foo = (bar: string): MyCurriedFunction => (tag: string, ...args: any[]) => {
    // do something
}

foo("str")("tag", ["one", "two"]); // fine
foo("str")("tag", {}, ["one", "two"]); // fine
foo("str")("tag", ["one", "two"], {}); // error
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20MyCurriedFunction%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20(tag%3A%20string%2C%20children%3F%3A%20string%5B%5D)%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20(tag%3A%20string%2C%20props%3A%20Object%2C%20children%3F%3A%20string%5B%5D)%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20foo%20%3D%20(bar%3A%20string)%3A%20MyCurriedFunction%20%3D%3E%20(tag%3A%20string%2C%20...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20do%20something%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afoo(%22str%22)(%22tag%22%2C%20%5B%22one%22%2C%20%22two%22%5D)%3B%20%2F%2F%20fine%0D%0Afoo(%22str%22)(%22tag%22%2C%20%7B%7D%2C%20%5B%22one%22%2C%20%22two%22%5D)%3B%20%2F%2F%20fine%0D%0Afoo(%22str%22)(%22tag%22%2C%20%5B%22one%22%2C%20%22two%22%5D%2C%20%7B%7D)%3B%20%2F%2F%20error))

Comment: That is clever!